# Place if statement inside a where clause in Linq for Entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

take the following.

```
       var query = context.Fields
            .Where( 
                x => x.DeletedAt == null 
            );

        // Apply search
        if( searchCriteria != null )
        {
            if( searchCriteria.SearchTerm != "" )
            {
                query.Where(
                    x => x.Location.Contains( searchCriteria.SearchTerm )
                );
            }
        }
```

this won't work because there are two where statements, they do not join up.

How would i do this statement? It might look like this:

```
var query = context.Fields
            .Where( 
                x => x.DeletedAt == null &&
                {
                    if( searchCriteria != null )
                    {
                        if( searchCriteria.SearchTerm != "" )
                        {
                            return x.Location.Contains( searchCriteria.SearchTerm );
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
```

Comment: `.Where( x=>{ ...if().... return something;} )`

Comment: How would i return multiple then? I have 1 x.DeletedAt query and 1 option Location query

Comment: Is the `if` testing against external conditions? Compose your query in multiple steps. `query = context.Table.Where(...original step...); query = query.Where(...additional step...);` etc.

Comment: ahhh do i have to do query = ... I'll try taht

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 What you write in `Where()` is a delegate. So how would you do it if you wrote a function?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram -Thanks man that worked, just had to put query = <> !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with the following:

```
    var query = context.Fields
        .Where( 
            x => x.DeletedAt == null 
        );

    // Apply search
    if( searchCriteria != null )
    {
        if( searchCriteria.SearchTerm != "" )
        {
            query = query.Where(
                x => x.Location.Contains( searchCriteria.SearchTerm )
            );
        }
    }
    return query;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to add the Where queries together?

Comment: Yes it does. It filters a filtered collection just once more.

Comment: You should have no problem chaining `Where()`'s onto your query like this unless you are trying to deal with something that linq to sql doesn't know how to interpret

Comment: query = was the missing part. Thanks mate!

Comment: Ahhhh it's beautiful, thankkk youuu... BAbehhhhhhhhh